# When should someone use Remote Attribute vs Custom Attribute

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

If I`m not mistaken, Remote Attribute Validate execute on Value Change, so it doesn't require you to press Submit, However Custom Attribute requires that we Write JQuery to call Adaptor

So my Question is why not use Remote Attribute all the time ?

Comment: `RemoteAttribute` is for calling a controller method to perform the validation. You would not do that if the validation can be performed on the client using javascript (for performance reasons)

Comment: sure you are right about this, but I'm talking about CustomAttribute with client validation.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your comment. If your custom ValidationAttribute implements `IClientValidatable`, then you add the necessary methods to the `jQuery.validator` so that you get client side validation performed on the client. Using a `RemoteAttribute` would just dramatically degrade performance (and would not give you server side validation which is most important)

Comment: now it makes sense, i would mark this as answer if you put it as Answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary purpose of a `RemoteAttribute` is to perform validation logic in the controller while staying on the same page. Most often its used when you need to access an external resource (for example to check that a new user is not using an existing user name when registering), but it could also be because the logic is so complex that it is not worth duplicating/maintaining it in a client side script.

Two important things to consider about the `RemoteAttribute`.

1. It uses ajax to make a call to a server side method. Initially the
   ajax call    is made after editing a control in the `.blur()` event,
   but thereafter on every `.keyup()` event so using a
   `RemoteAttribute` will be a performance hit
2. It provides only client side validation (which should only ever be
   considered a nice bonus) and you still need to then implement server
   side validation to prevent a malicious user by-passing the client
   side validation

If your writing a custom validation attribute where the validation logic can be performed using javascript, then your attribute should inherit from `ValidationAttribute` and implement `IClientValidatable` (and include the necessary scripts to add the client side rules) so that you get both client and server side validation without making unnecessary calls to the server.

Refer [The Complete Guide to Validation in ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2) for a good article on implementing custom validation attributes.